# How to adjust the height of the window dynamically in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a model window that contains expander control.

This expander control when expanded shows the user control which allow user to enter input through textboxes.

When expander control is collapsed it hides the user control.

I want when expander is collapsed or expanded the window will resize its height accordingly at run time.

Pleas help!!

Comment: Check out this guide on how to ask good questions: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I am extremely sorry Jens if I am not able to clear my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set property SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight", see also on [SizeToContent on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx)